# Generalized Hough Transform in OpenCV - set angle precision

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform, pattern-recognition

I have a problem with Generalized Hough Transform (Guil version) in OpenCV. My code:

```
def generalized_Hough():
    img = cv2.imread("img.png")
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    template = cv2.imread("template.png")
    height, width = template.shape[:2]

    edges = cv2.Canny(template, 200, 250)
    ght = cv2.createGeneralizedHoughGuil()
    ght.setTemplate(edges)

    ght.setMinDist(100)
    ght.setMinAngle(0)
    ght.setMaxAngle(360)
    ght.setAngleStep(1)
    ght.setLevels(360)
    ght.setMinScale(1)
    ght.setMaxScale(1.3)
    ght.setScaleStep(0.05)
    ght.setAngleThresh(100)
    ght.setScaleThresh(100)
    ght.setPosThresh(100)
    ght.setAngleEpsilon(1)
    ght.setLevels(360)
    ght.setXi(90)

    positions = ght.detect(img_gray)[0][0]

    for position in positions:
        center_col = int(position[0])
        center_row = int(position[1])
        scale = position[2]
        angle = int(position[3])

        found_height = int(height * scale)
        found_width = int(width * scale)

        rectangle = ((center_col, center_row),
                     (found_width, found_height),
                     angle)

        box = cv2.boxPoints(rectangle)
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv2.drawContours(img, [box], 0, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        for i in range(-2, 3):
            for j in range(-2, 3):
                img[center_row + i, center_col + j] = 0, 0, 255

    cv2.imwrite("results.png", img)
```

So I read image and template, get template as Canny edges, then configure GHT (Guil version for scale and angle) and plot detections. The problem is that the results are always snapped to nearest 90 degrees, despite setting angle min, max and step to 0, 360 and 1, respectively:

```
[[294. 110.   1. 270.]
 [100. 303.   1.   0.]
 [561. 312.   1.   0.]
 [461. 126.   1.  90.]
 [194. 109.   1.   0.]]
```

Image example:

[image]

Template example:

[image]

Results:

[image]

It's clearly visible that upper left and upper right detections are in more or less correct places and scales, but angle is wrong. How can I fix that?

Comment: I have not used that version of the hough transform, but have you checked whether the angle arguments are in degrees or radians?

Comment: @fmw42 they are in degrees, it's stated directly in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

ght.setXi(90)
set the angle to 90 degree difference change the value to 1 degree

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).